# Does the Diablo 3 hardcore mode have repair costs?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found a thread on a particular forum that said hardcore mode doesn't have repair costs. I don't have access to the game right now so I cannot test this, but would be grateful if someone answered it for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official 1.03 patch notes (current patch) [found here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/) they only mention the following:

> Repair costs have been increased for item levels between 53 and 63.

So far in playing both normal and hardcore, there is durability repair costs for both game types. As far as strict expensive repair costs go, only the normal game (softcore) has high repair costs, because if you die in hardcore mode, your character is done and lose all the items anyway.

Comment: Haha, I think I just understood why that thread said there were no repair costs lol. It was a joke on the fact that you perma-die! DOH!

Answer (score 2):

Like in the regular mode: any character under level 10, does not loose item durability.

*not to mention the death part :-)